# How to remove/change the BOT tag label on discord

Tags: tags, discord, bots

I wanna ask if someone knows how to remove or change to something else that https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmDUv.png BOT tag from a bot.

- Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The only change that can happen to the BOT tag is verify it with a tick. Otherwise, you cannot change the tag
https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412-Bot-Verification-and-Data-Whitelisting